# Why JSON.parse() won't get me the information from a json string in this case?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a string in json format, and I would like to select a specific item inside it and output it on the screen using .innerHTML.

I have a string called myData which is formatted as JSON.

The string is taken from a mySQL database using PHP.

To get them, I use this:

**I do fetch the items and I encode the array into a string in json format**

```
            $faqs = $traerFaqs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
            $stringFaqs = json_encode($faqs);
```

**And then I put it inside an item available to the DOM but hidden from view:**

```
            echo '<div id="hiloFaqs" style="display: none;">';
            echo $stringFaqs;
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
```

This is the string I get:

```
[
{"faqID":"1","tituloFaq":"Como accedo al material del Curso?","cuerpoFaq":"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<\/p>"
},
{"faqID":"2","tituloFaq":"Como cancelo los pagos del Curso?","cuerpoFaq":"
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo.<\/p>"
},
{"faqID":"3","tituloFaq":"Que documentacinn debo entregar?","cuerpoFaq":"
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.<\/p>"
},
{
"faqID":"4","tituloFaq":"Por que estoy suspendido?","cuerpoFaq":"
Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<\/p>"
},{
"faqID":"5","tituloFaq":"Por que estoy pendiente?","cuerpoFaq":"
Kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.<\/p>"
}
]
```

Now, I'm trying to get a particular item and for some reason I can't.
I'm new to JS, so maybe I'm forgetting something very silly here:

```
var faqs = document.getElementById("hiloFaqs");
var myData = faqs.textContent;
faq = JSON.parse(myData);
$('#output').append(faq[0]['tituloFaq']);
```

I do have the output in place in my html file, like this: `<span id="output"></span>`, but nothing gets printed out.

Shouldn't `faq[0]['tituloFaq']` get me *Como accedo al material del Curso?* outputted?

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you echoing it out into html? Also `htmlspecialchars($stringFaqs);` is going to modify it so the characters no longer make a valid json string

Comment: Would be easier to just echo it in a script tag, as  a real javascript object ?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: `<script>var faqs = <?php echo json_encode($faqs); ?></script>`

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. No, I want just some of the stuff inside the json string.

Answer (score 0):

First thing there is no need to capture the JSON from within a hidden text node. Instead assign it inline right away as a global javascript variable.

```
<script>
var MY_DATA = JSON.parse(<?=$stringFaqs;?>);
// or
var MY_DATA = JSON.parse(<?php echo $stringFaqs; ?>);
</script>
```

Give that a go.

Comment: take off `JSON.parse`, if you print the return value from `json_encode` you will get a valid javascript value already. Otherwise you will have something like `JSON.parse({})` which will give an invalid token error

Comment: You shouldn't have `JSON.parse` in either example. The string is already JavaScript, you can just drop it into the page, and `JSON.parse` will die because you're passing it a JavaScript array, not a string.

Comment: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php Scroll down. You want to use JSON.parse for encoding reasons. "Although it is not always necessary to run the results of json_encode through a parser on the JavaScript side, you will generally want to do so"